# Rastertospl failed samsung printer

Tags: driver, cups

I have connected my Samsung M2020 Series printer connected to RPI with CUPS. The printer is set up and I installed proper drivers for this printer on the RPI. CUPS recognised it and I selected it. The printer is successfully set up in CUPS, but when I try printing the test page, it is not working. The problem is with rastertospl. It is not installed. I tried `sudo apt-get install printer-driver-splix` and rebooting the pi, but that didn't work. I don't know how to install the rastertospl, please help.

The printer status is:  Idle - "File "/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl" not available: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1):

No wonder it does not exist on a Debian Buster system, which the current Pi OS is based on..

```
root@buster-raspi:~# apt-file search /cups/filter/rastertospl
root@buster-raspi:~# apt-file search /cups/filter/r
cups: /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertodymo   
cups: /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertoepson
cups: /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertohp
cups: /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertolabel
cups: /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertopwg
cups-filters: /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertoescpx
cups-filters-core-drivers: /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertopclm
cups-filters-core-drivers: /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertopclx
cups-filters-core-drivers: /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertopdf
cups-filters-core-drivers: /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertops
printer-driver-brlaser: /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertobrlaser
printer-driver-dymo: /usr/lib/cups/filter/raster2dymolm
printer-driver-dymo: /usr/lib/cups/filter/raster2dymolw
printer-driver-gutenprint: /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertogutenprint.5.3
printer-driver-oki: /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertookidotmatrix
printer-driver-oki: /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertookimonochrome
printer-driver-ptouch: /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertoptch
printer-driver-sag-gdi: /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertosag-gdi
printer-driver-splix: /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertoqpdl
```

The closest to it is the package you installed it has the `/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertoqpdl` so could be typo in their configuration, old name...

To test my theory give the command below a go.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertoqpdl /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl
```

This will symbolically link the existing file to the name it looks for.